# Gearman Job Server and PHP Extension

Tags: server, php

How may I install Gearman Job Server and PHP Extension on my Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop? I've already installed latest version of PHP on my Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop.

I've to run my custom Script with Gearman. Would anyone please help me about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find on Launchpad last version of [Gearman Server and Client Libraries(Gearman Server and Client Libraries)](https://launchpad.net/gearmand). After you download it ([gearman-1.1.7.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.7/+download/gearmand-1.1.7.tar.gz)) you have all instructions about how you can to install here: [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

More about: http://gearman.org/download.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answer me. I downloaded Gearman Server and Client Libraries form Launchpad but I didn't find any kind of Install file on there. I read your all URL but it didn't help me at all. Would you please let me know anymore details?

Comment: @SumonKhan I gave you the download link: [gearman-1.1.7.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.7/+download/gearmand-1.1.7.tar.gz). This is the package thet you must to install (how you didn't find it?). Did you read [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Hi,
I didn't find any installer file that I could install with your documentation. It wasn't work for me. That's what I meant to you :(

Comment: @SumonKhan How didn't worked? What problems did you encounter?